# Run the CPUMiner-multi mining package with the Mosix clustering package

Tags: ubuntu, cluster

When I run the CPUMiner-multi package for 'xmr' digital coin mining in Ubuntu Linux under the Mosix-4.4.4 clustering package with two nodes

```
$ ./mosrun -e ./minerd -a cryptonight -p stratum+tcp://frankfurt-1.xmrpool.net:5555 - u MY_WALLET_ADDRESS -p MY PASSWORD
```

this error message appears:

> Using JSON-RPC 2.0 workio thread create failed

Comment: `- u` or `-u` ?

Comment: sorry , -u is correct

Comment: Did you get this working? Would it not be easier to just run two miners? I can't see how clustering would improve anything (though I would be interested in seeing it work).

Comment: Do you have all the correct dependencies installed?

Comment: This is a research work And I hope I can do it.It is the processor and memory sharing in the network for cpu mining operations.If you have any experience with this case, thank you for sharing it.

Comment: Yes, separate cpuminer-multi and Mosix each run properly, but not with each other.